# Ripple effect on NavigationView item

Tags: android, drawerlayout, android-navigationview, clicklistener

I have NavigationView in my DrawerLayout and let's say it has simple menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Now I set listener for click:

```
mNavigationVeiw.setOnNavigationItemSelected(this);

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            SettingsActivity.startActivity(this);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that I don't see ripple effect. When I long press on item, the ripple is showing, but with click it's not working. I think the problem is that I open Activity after click instead of replacing fragments, and my menu should have addition options. How can I fix that?

**EDIT**

Everything works fine when I set `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` but in my case it's not this behavior, cause I'm launching another activity and it should not check clicked item, because in this new Activity is back button on the top instead of access navigation drawer.

Comment: you need to populate your navigation drawer using list items.

Comment: which `support library version` are you using ?

Comment: android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: I eddited question. I'm using the newest support library version.

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Ripple-Animation

Answer (score 2):

Add itemBackground into NavigationView inside your xml file the following attribute:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_navigation_selector"
```

Also, inside the drawable-v21 folder, add ripple_navigation_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/submit_btn_ripple_color" >

    <item android:drawable="@color/accentColor" />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</ripple>
```

Comment: Missing some information here. Why are there two drawables within the ripple selector? Which does what?